# beutiful soup element not returning Text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
x=requests.get("http://www.ip-score.com/")
import bs4
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(x.text,"lxml")
x=soup.find("span",{"id":"spamhouse"})
print(x.getText())
```

But it is showing only ' '
i.e empty string

But it should show "Clear" or "LowRisk"

Comment: In the page source code I see this: `<span id="spamhouse"></span>`, so it's normal that you get an empty string. Which part of the page are you trying to capture?

Comment: Depending on you reply to @Stergios, you might need to use another software product such as selenium to scrape what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content in the span tag is loaded via xhr request to ajax api: `/ajax_handler/check_bl/all` (found by inspecting the network traffic in browser).
You can get a json response from the api, but first you'll have to grab your ip from the page.

```
import requests
import bs4

r = requests.get("http://www.ip-score.com")
ip = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml").select_one("div#MaxMind a").string
r = requests.post('http://www.ip-score.com/ajax_handler/check_bl/all', data={'ip':ip})
data = r.json()['spamhouse']
print(data)
```

Alternatively you can use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for js generated content.

Comment: Wow. How did you find that ajax api and the data it accepts?

Comment: @Stergios open the page in your browser, use inspect, go to the network tab and filter by xhr. You'll notice a POST request to the api. If you click on it you'll see the post data in the headers (or params for firefox) tab.